# What is this weird gate?

Tags: terminology, computer-architecture, logic, notation

[image: odd not gate]

This came from a picture of something that I'm supposed to make, and I can't find it in the program I'm supposed to use (LogicWorks). It looks like it 'not's only one of its inputs, but that doesn't make sense because that input comes from a not gate (not pictured here); it would make more sense for this part to be no gate at all, just two connected wires.

It would be helpful to say what this is called and/or what it does.

Comment: It's "three-state buffer active high" - please see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86803/circuit-schematic-symbol-for-buffer-with-control-input

Comment: About three-state buffers in general: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-state_logic